# Service Unavailable Central administration SharePoint 2010

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i am facing a problem with my SharePoint Administration 2010, when i am trying to open it its give me 
"Service Unavailable"

but the other sites that are created are working fine. 
i searched the net but i didn't find a good site for this problem

any help please

Comment: does it give a correlation id? if so, what (if anything) does ULS say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing **Application pool identity to Network-Service** and i restart the IIS and it worked